# Recursive query to get all descendants of row

Tags: sql, recursion

I have a Menu system where each item can have a parent. So the structure is something like this

[image]

What I want to do is display a 'bread crumb' style list of links for the current page. So if the user was on ~/CVR.aspx, I'd want the following displayed:

CVR Control - CVR

So I need to a SQL query that'd recursively get a list of all parent menu items, up until the parent on a row is null).

Any ideas?

Comment: The screenshot and `.aspx` suggest SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

For SQL-Server, you can do this using a simple CTE:

```
WITH MenuCTE AS
(
  SELECT Id, parent, Text, Url
  FROM menu
  WHERE Id = 8
  UNION ALL
  SELECT p.Id, p.parent, p.Text, p.Url
  FROM MenuCTE c
  INNER JOIN menu p ON c.parent = p.id
)
SELECT *
FROM MenuCTE ;
```

### [Live Demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/82265/recursive-query-to-get-all-descendants-of-row)

For example for the id = 8 this should give you:

```
Id  parent     Text             Url
8     6        CVR           ~/cvr.aspx
6    NULL   CVR Control   ~/CVRDashboard.aspx
```